# I do not have permission to write into iCloud folder

Tags: ios, swift, icloud-drive, icloud-documents

I'm trying to write a file into ubiquitous folder, I can run a query and all works fine, I see the files, but If I try to set a local file I obtain this error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“video.mp4” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “DemoExample”." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3C3DC6B5-7B22-4B1C-B8AB-187F640F68AB/DemoExample.app/video.mp4, NSUserStringVariant=(
Move
), NSDestinationFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~Test~DemoExample/Documents/video.mp4, NSFilePath=/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3C3DC6B5-7B22-4B1C-B8AB-187F640F68AB/DemoExample.app/video.mp4, NSUnderlyingError=0x17405c5c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

Video.mp4 exists in folder, what wrong?

here is the code for save file:

```
try self.fileManager.setUbiquitous(true, itemAt: URL.init(fileURLWithPath:file.path), destinationURL: iCloudUrl)
```

I use this:

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
<dict>
    <key>iCloud.com.Test.DemoExample</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
        <true/>
    <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
    <string>backup</string>
    <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
    <string>Any</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: You misunderstood @aeger's comment (or they didn't explain well). Answers belong in answers, not in questions. You were right to post your own solution in an answer. To sum up: do not post answers in questions, and do not post questions in answers. Questions belong in questions, and answers belong in answers - that's all. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps one by one. Hope it will solve your problem....

1. Enable iCloud from Capabilities under XCode settings area.

[image]

2. Update your AppID and provisioning profile by enabling iCloud.

[image]

3. Add below property in your info.plist.

> ```
> <key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
> <dict>
>     <key>iCloud.YOUR_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER</key>
>     <dict>
>         <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
>         <true/>
>         <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
>         <string>Any</string>
>         <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
>         <string>iCloudDriveDemo</string>
>     </dict>
> </dict>
> ```

4. **iCloud.YOUR_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER is very important here. For example your bundle identifier is “com.emraz.myapp”. Then you have to use “iCloud.com.emraz.myapp”**

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (@emraz didn't work for me):

1. Uninstall the app on all devices
2. Delete the folder in the Files.app
   (iOS) if visible.
3. Delete every folder related to the
   application from ~/Library/Application
   Support/CloudDocs/session/containers
4. Delete every folder related to
   the application from ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/
5. Reboot after a few minutes
6. Remove the Scheme you are using in XCode
7. Add back a new Scheme (same name is ok)